# Delete data in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not sure how to explain my problem so i am showing the sample data.

I have the following table

```
---------------------------------
|RecID |TypeOfData  |Data       |
|21    |Label       |Name       |
|21    |Data        |Sam        |
|22    |Label       |Name       |
|23    |Label       |Name       |
|23    |Data        |Nimble     |
```

I want to delete all those Label records which do not have Data Below them.
So in above example the RecID=22 needs to be deleted.

Kindly help me with this.

Db is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Shiva See RecID 21 and RecID 22.  Rec ID dosent have Data below Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you can use a subselect where the count of Rec_id is =1

```
  delete from my_table 
  where Rec_id in (select RecID from my_table 
                   group by RecId 
                   having count(*) =1)
 and TypeOdData = 'Label'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
delete t
    from t
    where t.typeofdata = 'Label' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.recid = t.recid and t2.typeofdata = 'Data'
                     );
```

"below" doesn't mean anything in a relational table, because the table represents an *unordered* set.

Comment: @NimbleFungus . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  You can choose whichever answer you like, but I'm curious.

Comment: I choose other over this as i was not willing to not use NOT Exist . Thats only reason. Thanks...!! i wanted to mark both as answer.

Comment: @NimbleFungus . . . That's a shame because `NOT EXISTS` probably performs better than the answer using a subquery with `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(TypeOfData, Data, Rn) 
AS
(
SELECT [TypeOfData], [Data], 
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TypeOfData, DATA ORDER BY TypeOfData,Data)
FROM tbl
WHERE TypeOfData ='label'
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```